# Iterative Inorder Traversal B-Tree

Tags: java, b-tree, inorder

My end goal is to do a `findKthElement` function and the only way I can think of is to perform iterative inorder traversal so that I can keep a counter, which obviously doesn't work if its recursive. I have tried my best at an implementation similar to a BST but its not working, just printing the same thing infinately. Here is my attempt:

```
public void findKth() {
        Stack<BTreeNode> s = new Stack<>();
        BTreeNode current = this.root;
        while(current != null || !s.isEmpty()) {
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < current.numNodes; i++) {
                if(!current.isLeaf) {
                    s.push(current);
                    current = current.children[i];
                }
            }
            current = s.pop();
            for(int j = 0; j < current.numNodes; j++) {
                System.out.println(current.keys[j].getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Changing `current` in the for-loop? Play with pen and paper what you want to do.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You'll need either a stack of node and index into that node (to go to the next node entry), or check the entire node's values and find the insert position using subtree counts.

Comment: Well I have a Stack of nodes? Do you mins showing what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> keep a counter, which obviously doesn't work if its recursive

There is no problem keeping a counter in a recursive solution. You just need to make sure it's a mutable reference. For example:

```
public class Counter {
    private int count;
    public boolean complete() { return count == 0; }
    public void decrement() { count--; }
}

Optional<Node> findKthChild(Node node, Counter counter) {
    if (counter.isLeaf()) {
        if (counter.complete())
            return Optional.of(node);
        counter.decrement();
    } else {
        for (Node child: getChildren()) {
            Optional<Node> kthChild = findKthChild(child, counter);
            if (kthChild.isPresent())
                return kthChild;
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

If you're familiar with streams the internal for loop could be:

```
return getChildren().stream()
    .map(ch -> findKthChild(ch, counter))
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .findFirst().orElse(Optional.empty());
```

Comment: It seems like this is returning the kth Node, and not the kth element, so if a Node holds several keys (elements) then it would return that whole Node, and not the specific kth element? Either way its not returning the correct Node.

Comment: @LukaJozić I hadn't realised you wanted to ignore nodes without elements. Have edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

This reeks of home work. One should try to solve it by tracing the needed steps manually, with pen and paper.

I am not claiming that the code below is correct, or good.

It is to indicate that an in-order traversal, depth first, needs to come back a some nodes i<sup>th</sup> sub-branch to continue with the next child.

For that I use the new *record* class as stack element, a class consisting of just `BTreeNode node` and `int index`.

```
public String findKth(int k) {
    record NodePos(BTreeNode node, int index) {};
    Stack<NodePos> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(new NodePos(this.root, -1);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        NodePos pos = stack.pop();
        pos = new NodePos(pos.node, pos.index + 1);
        if (pos.index >= pos.node.numNodes) { // Past end of child nodes.
            continue;
        }
        // Sub-branch:
        if (!pos.node.isLeaf) {
            stack.push(new NodePos(pos.node.children[pos.index], -1);
            continue;
        }
        // Key:
        if (pos.index + 1 >= pos.node.numNodes) { // Past end of child keys.
            continue;
        }
        System.console().printf("%d. %s%n", k, pos.node.keys[pos.index]);
        if (k <= 0) {
            return pos.node.keys[pos.index];
        }
        --k;
        stack.push(pos);
    }
}
```

There are `numNodes` sub-branches (`node.children`)and `numNodes - 1` keys in a node (`node.keys`).

When you are at the *i* th sub-branch, you may first continue with the subtree, and when not sufficient (decreasing k still greater 0), then continue with the *i-1* th key.

As you see, when not manually executing the code, it is hard to read it. For that it invaluable advice to work out these things yourself.

A recursive solution is easier by the way.

---

***Okay, a working solution***

My answer above was intended to think about, certainly not correct,
as the OP did not show having seriously thought about the algorithm,
given the OPs code. But there is effort evidently.

Hence a readable recursive solution. Still in a form which cannot
be given back as ones own home work.

```
static class BTreeNode {
    int numNodes;
    boolean isLeaf;
    BTreeNode[] children;
    int[] keys;

    BTreeNode(int... keys) {
        numNodes = keys.length + 1;
        this.keys = keys.clone();
        isLeaf = true;
    }

    public void addChildren(BTreeNode... children) {
        assert children.length == numNodes;
        this.children = children.clone();
        isLeaf = false;
    }
}

public static OptionalInt findKth(BTreeNode node, AtomicInteger k) {
    if (node == null || k.get() < 0) {
        return OptionalInt.empty();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < node.numNodes; ++i) {
        if (!node.isLeaf) {
            OptionalInt result = findKth(node.children[i], k);
            if (result.isPresent()) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        if (i + 1 < node.numNodes) {
            int j = k.getAndDecrement();
            System.out.printf("%d. %s%n", j, node.keys[i]);
            if (j <= 0) {
                return OptionalInt.of(node.keys[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return OptionalInt.empty();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //
    //       (4       8        12)
    // (1 2 3) (5 6 7) (9 10 11) (13 14 15)
    BTreeNode n1to3 = new BTreeNode(1, 2, 3);
    BTreeNode n5to7 = new BTreeNode(5, 6, 7);
    BTreeNode n9to11 = new BTreeNode(9, 10, 11);
    BTreeNode n13to15 = new BTreeNode(13, 14, 15);
    BTreeNode root = new BTreeNode(4, 8, 12);
    root.addChildren(n1to3, n5to7, n9to11, n13to15);

    OptionalInt key5 = findKth(root, new AtomicInteger(5));
    System.out.println("The result is " + key5.orElse(-1));
}
```

One walks in-order through the B-tree decrementing the asked k till it reaches 0. The in-order walk with *numNodes* subtree branches and *numNodes - 1* keys requires a for+if.

The AtomicInteger is used to have a counter, a result from `findKth` otherwise one would need an input parameter k, and a new value for k on return. That can be done.

Optimisation: One could skip visiting a subtree, if one knew the number of elements in an entire subtree. For leaf nodes that would be numNodes.

Comment: Trust me I have tried for a long time to work it out myself.. Though I appreciate the effort this does not work. If you feel up to showing the recursive approach I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I did not want to provide a _working_ solution, as it is so much fun top puzzle out ones own algorithm. But I am sorry it did not lead to something. I added a simple recursive solution you can play with.